# Update data from a new JSON after delay of 5 seconds and again from a new JSon after another 5 delays sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

my updated full script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                 $.getJSON('table.json',function(data){

                    $('#mytable').empty(); 
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<tr class="tableheader"><th>Name</th><th>Code</th><th>Value</th><th>Bid</th><th>Offer</th></tr>';
                    for (var i=0, size=data.length; i<size;i++) {                           
                            html += '<tr class="tablecontent"><td>'+ data[i].name+ '</td><td>'+ data[i].code+ '</td><td>'
                                         + data[i].value+ '</td><td>'
                                         +data[i].bid+'</td><td>'+data[i].offer+'</td></tr>';
                            }

            $('#mytable').append(html);
            tablerows('mytable');
            setTimeout(poll,5000);

        });




        });

        var poll = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "dummy.json",
        success: function(data){
        //HANDLE DATA
         setTimeout(poll,5000);
    }
   });
},5000);
```

Please help me in this. i have 3 JSONs. 1st Json will load initially. That is done.

2nd json needs to be parsed (which has 2 field changes) and show the initial json + changed fields and then again from 3rd JSON.

I have written below script:

```
var poll = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "dummy.json",
        success: function(data){
        //HANDLE DATA
         JSON.parse(data); 
    }
   });
},5000)
```

dummy.json is my second changed JSON. Is this the correct way?how should i call this function function in my $(document).ready?

Comment: You do not need `JSON.parse`; jQuery already does that for you.

Comment: Is the only reason your using setInterval to ensure your first result, etc. has returned?

Comment: yes Liam. but the data is not getting updated after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it as a regular function and then call it from itself within the success handler so then you are never getting ahead of yourself. Then you can also just call it once from your $(document).ready.

```
var poll = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "dummy.json",
        success: function(data){
        //HANDLE DATA
            setTimeout(poll,5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it updating the first time? Is any data coming back from the ajax call?

Comment: Please see above my full script. And tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: If you are using the setTimeout method then you don't need the setInteval method too as they both essentially do the same thing (athough setTimeout will be queueing rather than just trying every 5 seconds, success or fail).

Comment: then how should i go if i only want to use setTimeout?

Comment: Replace your poll function with the one in my original reply. As above though, is the data updating after the initial load and is any data coming back from the dummy.json call?

Comment: i just checked. i am not able to get data from dummy.json.any idea why is that?

Comment: i am not able to understand. File exists in same folder. validated through JSONLint also. [{ 
 "code": "APPL",
 "bid": "100"
},
{
 "code": "NOK",
 "offer": "10",
 "value": "11"
}]

Comment: which is why its not updating. how to access array now?

Comment: Maybe use .getJSON rather than ajax in the poll function. Is your dummy.json return with the correct content type?